# Create Independent Pages

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a project that needs to have the same page running independent from the calling page and the other instance of the the same page.
To illustrate the situation I believe this picture helps:
[image]

And the Page1 has lots of forwards to the same page that I changed to MasterPage... This way the left page (the first to be called from code) works well showing all contents correctly but not the second one.

This is how I called the pages:

```
<div style="zoom: 75%; float: left; width: 50%;">
    <div style="zoom: 75%; float: left; width: 50%;">
<jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include>
</div>
<div style="zoom: 75%; float: right; width: 50%;">
    <jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include>
</div>
```

And the `index.jsp` has a few fields inside a form and at the bottom a canvas tag that is going to display information, gets a few paramaters and sends to a servlet, and the the servlet makes a few things and forward to `index.jsp` (that I changed to my `masterpage` to see the two results). But the way it is now just displays the values for the first called page and the second one just the form withtout the canvas.

I was thinking of somehow make the master page "static" and only update the divs that holds the includes tag. But I don't know if this will work since I have the forward method...

Then how can I call the same page twice and forwards to the same without loosing content of the other page and inside a master page? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you want to load the divs with Ajax rather than jsp:include.

Comment: If I use `$("#leftPage").load("index.jsp");` my canvas isn't created

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that doesn't create because doens't call my servlet from index.jsp using `.load()`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2702780/1065197.